# how does ElasticSearch set the filtering in a group query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

In this official site
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html

they have this query:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

and then say it is similar to :

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM bank GROUP BY state ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

my question is where is the mapping?

is it that when selecting the properties inside the `terms` part, that means the `select state, count(*)` ?

and where is the code in that elasticsearch query that is states to order desc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
"group_by_state": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "state"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Its sql analogy as you mentioned is `SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM bank GROUP BY state ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

We defined terms aggregation above which is a type of `bucket aggregation`.It returns a list of buckets which contains

- **Key**: unique terms indexed for a given field
- **doc_count**: No. of matching documents

The `field` value inside terms aggregation defines two things:

- Which column is to be used for grouping (`state` in our case (This refers to `GROUP BY state` in sql))
- What will be the key of bucket (unique values of `state` indexed in our case.(This refers to `SELECT state` in sql ))

`doc_count` which refers to `count *` in `sql` is being returned as we are using `bucket aggregation`.

Terms aggregation by default returns the buckets ordered by the doc_count which is analogous to `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` in sql.

Hope this replies all your queries.

Answer (score 1):

What did you mean with "mapping"?

The `terms` is an aggregation type, which will return each bucket containing the key (in this case the `state` field value) and the count of this term along all retrieved docs.

The ordering by count desc is the Elasticsearch default, so it's implicit.

Output example:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Florida",
          "doc_count": 10
        },
        {
          "key": "Rio de Janeiro",
          "doc_count": 8
        },
        {
          "key": "Lisbon",
          "doc_count": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: there are two "state" words, which one reference that I'm aggregating on the `state` attribute, and which one tells that I wan the `state` to be in the output with its count

Comment: the state is retrieved as well...updated my answer with an elasticsearch response example